# Trying to centre multiple icons with text

Tags: html, css, wordpress

Just a quick and simple one here.

I'm trying to center a series of 6 icons w/text using additional css on my wordpress website.

How do I locate and center these all together?

I can't tell you how much I appreciate your time

Comment: Hello Pete and welcome to Stackoverflow. You need to provide the code that you are working with, a proper explanation of what it is you need help with, what you've tried and where you are stuck with it. Please read this guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Plz, provide code or link to the website.